# Yii: How to create sql with CDbCriteria

Tags: yii

SQL is :

```
select name, value from config where parent_id in ( select id from config where
name = 'Yii');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your condition but try to add sub query on condition field

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select ='name, value';
$criteria->addCondition( select id from config where name = 'Yii');
```